Why is "one function do more than one thing" a disadvantage of "boolean parameter", but not in "polymorphism"?
According to Is it wrong to use a boolean parameter to determine behavior?, I know using boolean parameters to decide the behaviour is bad, for example, when using boolean parameters as the following:
public void doSomething(boolean condition){
    if (condition) {
        // do something when true
    } else {
        // do something when false
    }
}

obj.doSomething(true); //some code to call the function

I should refactor it into 2 functions:
public void doSomethingWhenTrue{
    // do something when condition is true
}

public void doSomethingWhenFalse{
    // do something when condition is false
}

obj.doSomethingWhenTrue(); //some code to call the function

And I know it has similar reasons to tell a function with switch over enums is bad : How does this switch statement do "multiple things"?.
However, what I don't know is, why is "one function do more than one thing" a disadvantage of "boolean parameters", but not in polymorphism? When I'm using polymorphism, I'm also calling the same function name but potentially resulting different behaviours:
public interface Condition {
    public void doSomething();
}

public class True implements Condition {
    public void doSomething() {
        // something to do when condition is true
    }
}

public class False implements Condition {
    public void doSomething() {
        // something to do when condition is false
    }
}

When calling doSomething:
var condition = new True();
condition.doSomething();

It feels as if the boolean parameter is just moving from right hand side to left hand side only. But I guess you will not say polymorphism is bad because of "one function do more than one thing", right?
So my question is, while both "boolean parameter" and "polymorphism" are fundamentally "calling same function name but can have different behaviour", why is it bad when the behaviour is determined by the boolean parameter at right hand side, but not bad (and even good) when it is determined by the object type at left hand side?

Your question is only valid when polymorphism is applied inappropriately. And then the answer is "don't do that".
The purpose of polymorphism is not to provide a switch into different functionalities. The purpose is to provide a switch into different implementations of the same function depending on the type of object.
So with polymorphism it should always be "one thing", one operation on a functional level. Which may be implemented differently among types.


It feels as if the boolean parameter is just moving from right hand side to left hand side only

It shouldn't feel that way. And if you refactor this code smell just to do that you likely have not done anyone any favors. Before trying to fix it lets look into why this smell is a problem.
I contend that their are two fundamental reasons this is a smell: structure and semantics. You are poking holes in the structure argument. And you have a point.
This code smell goes by many names:
Robert Martin called them Boolean Arguments

Boolean arguments loudly declare that the function does more than one thing. They are confusing and should be eliminated.
informit.com Eliminate Boolean Arguments

Said that way this is a structure argument. Read the rest of the article though and it's dripping with a semantic argument. More on that later.
The structure argument here is that a function should only do one thing and one that modifies its behavior based on a boolean does two.
You contend that condition.doSomething(); does the same thing. And you're right. But this design complies with a much older design principle than "do one thing". This complies with the zero-one-infinity rule which states a good design only ever specifies the number of elements in it with one of three numbers: 0, 1 or as many as you like. This design is better because, done this way, it's much easier to introduce a 3rd condition. Or a 4th. Or... The real structural problem with passing Bools is that they leave you stuck on 2.
Sure, an add function will add more than one expression. It will add many expressions. I've never seen a well designed add function that only ever added two expressions. Someone might argue that such an add function only does one thing but sorry that's still crap. A design that sticks you with a two because it thinks it knew the future better than you know the present is not your friend.
Now that's a strictly structural argument. Which is the weak argument against passing Bools. Semantics is the much better argument.
Go and read the rest of that article and you'll see calling code such as:
int status = fuelRod.rotate(0.5, true);

Which, semantically, is much better than
obj.doSomething(true);

But it's still crap. Oh sure, I know fuel rods are being rotated. Much better than only knowing we're doing something to some object. But we still don't know what's true about any of this. Oh sure, you can look inside and see how true is used. But screw you for expecting me to do that. No seriously. If you think good code forces people to click inside to understand, rather than providing a helpful abstraction that keeps you from being surprised by what's inside, then screw you. People like that have wasted so much of my time.
This is the strong argument. It's not about structure. It's about semantics and what they communicate. It just isn't usually argued as well here because if you take it seriously it doesn't necessarily care about the Bool. I'll demonstrate with some code examples:
int status = fuelRod.rotateByRadians(0.5);

is better than
int status = fuelRod.rotate(0.5, true);

but so is
int status = fuelRod.rotate(0.5, radians:true);

Problem is, that last one isn't legal Java (it's legal C#). But it largely solves the semantic problem. Just not the structural one (suppose someone wants fractions of turns).
There's more than one reason to avoid passing Bools, more than one way to avoid passing them, and some of those ways don't really help.
Rod fuelRod = new FuelRod.builder().useRadians().build();
int status = fuelRod.rotate(0.5);

Ugg.
I'd say this
int status = fuelRod.rotateByRadians(0.5);

is the clear winner here. But to apply that to your example I need better names than obj and doSomething. Please don't ignore the semantics.

This smell goes by other names.
c2.com called it False Unification of Procedures

A procedure, function, or method has a boolean that provides a variation on its behavior, but the two variations in fact have completely different semantics. It would be better to refactor the common code into another method and split the remainder into two separate methods, removing the boolean.
c2.com Code Smell

Martin Fowler called it a Flag Argument:

My reasoning here is that the separate methods communicate more clearly what my intention is when I make the call. Instead of having to remember the meaning of the flag variable when I see book(martin, false) I can easily read regularBook(martin).
martinfowler.com Flag Argument


You might instead have fuelRod.rotateBy(new Radians(0.5)), which is also using polymorphism. It does require a robust units library to be nice tho.

Maybe int status = fuelRod.rotate(new Radians(0.5));.  (Your answer turned into a rant midway. I feel you, though.)

Heh, yeah, like I said, there’s more than one way to avoid passing them.

TLDR: the decision and the code to implement it should be close to each other
The advice is meant to help finding places of tight coupling, which would benefit from dependency inversion. To fully understand it, you need to consider three parties:

decision maker
caller
callee

If your polymorphic behavior is following Liskov Substitution Principle, a method call is indeed only doing one thing. The distinction between a method parameter and virtual dispatch is in the knowledge and responsibilities distribution.

parameter value has to be known to the caller, so the decision and choice of execution branch is made by caller
virtual dispatch hides the decision from caller and it is made by callee, but as calee is focused on single brach, it does the only thing it can.

So virtual dispatch removes knowledge,  choice, and decision from both caller and callee, achieving "single thing" goal.
The decision is now made by dependency injection dispatcher at undefined higher layer, much earlier. It might seem that moving decision elsewhere is meaningless, but as more and more context is initialized as early as possible and aggregated it:

enforces "fail early" policy
concentrates knowledge of a single concept in a single place (improves cohesion), by grouping callee and decision maker
simplifies all other code (reduces coupling)


I feel the need to push back on this idea that boolean parameters are necessarily a code smell.  It really depends on what the boolean parameter is used for and the context of the calls to the function/method.
At a very general level, adding a boolean parameter could be a valid and useful way to define a method if the value of that parameter needs to be determined at runtime.  If the value of a boolean parameter is always known at development time, then see candied_orange's answer. I don't see a need to reiterate that explanation.
As a counter-example, consider a method that returns a value from a cache. Most of the time, you want the cache to do its thing and refresh based on its internal logic. There may be times, however, that a cached value is not acceptable based on some runtime state of the application or perhaps based on external inputs.
In that case, having two methods (or classes, yikes!) for this means you have to do things like this:
public void get_something(String key){
    if (forceCacheRefreshExpressionResult) {
        cache.getWithRefresh(key);
    } else {
        cache.get(key);
    }
}

Which is pretty ugly, IMO. What I would prefer is a cache interface like this:
<T> get(String key);
<T> get(String key, boolean forceRefresh);

And the previous call becomes:
public void get_something(String key){
    cache.get(key, forceCacheRefreshExpressionResult);
}

Without having to specify the extra parameter everywhere the get call is made.
Note that in this case, this function isn't "doing two things". The cache could refresh a value on any call. All this is doing is overriding the default logic for when a value should be refreshed. In the cache implementation itself it's probably just an OR condition.
If your boolean parameter results in branching into two very different execution paths, then it's almost surely a bad design.  And if you never need to determine the boolean's value using runtime logic, it's probably best to have separate methods, at least on the interface.

If you think of it as "changing behavior", at first blush it does like they're contradictory statements. But that's not the reason why either guideline is given.
In both cases, the focal point is that consumers should not be responsible for knowing the internal logic of the component they're consuming.
Your examples focus on the implementation of that component. I'm intentionally removing that from my snippets, instead giving you the perspective of the consumer.
ReduceStockLevelBy(purchaseRequest.ProductId, purchaseRequest.Amount, false);

What does the last parameter do? You can't tell. Okay, but that's not entirely fair because the consumer (dev) does get IDE help to indicate the values, so I'll give you that as well: the name of that param is sendAlertWhenGoingIntoNegativeAmount.
Sure, you can infer that this controls whether or not negative stock amounts are allowed. But does it send an alert after altering the stock level, or does it send an alert instead of altering the stock level?
You don't know this. And you may be tempted to now go into the code and find this out, but the problem here is that if you repeatedly design your code with that expectation in mind, then you are building a codebase where you continually have to dig deeper and deeper before you understand how to do anything.
Worse still, what if tomorrow there are two kinds of alerts? Now you have to not only add a parameter for the customer to select which kind of alert to send, but you now also have to revisit every consumer of your component and update their usage of your component.
Let's look at how you could solve this using inheritance (to get ahead of commenters: I'm not saying inheritance is the best solution here, I'm just comparing the example scenario). This is what it looks like from a consumer's point of view:
var stock = repository.GetStockForProduct(purchaseRequest.ProductId);

stock.ReduceBy(purchaseRequest.Amount);

I've skipped over details such as letting the consumer know if they're able to take this stock or not - that's a distraction to the core focus of this answer.
How the stock should behave when this goes into the negatives is not visible here, because the code has been set up to not force the consumer to make that decision. Instead, the decision of stock behavior can now be made by someone else. The consumer here simply interacts with the (preconfigured) stock.
In this scenario, the consumer is no longer forced to understand the alerting rules when all they really cared about is trying to get some stock to satisfy a purchase request. They didn't need to know what the alerting requirements are, so it didn't make sense to force them to figure out if and how to raise alerts.
That is the key goal of the advice: don't make your consumer responsible for knowing your component's internals. Phrasing the same advice from a developer's perspective: build your code in a way that you don't need to know how everything works all at once, because (a) it's harder to learn and remember, (b) it's more likely that you're going to make a mistake and (c) it's going to be significantly harder to make alterations to this logic in the future without introducing bugs or regressions.
If you want a real world analogy: imagine if you were trying to buy a soda from a machine, and instead of labeled buttons, you get a bunch of loose electrical wires.
If you wanted to, you could inspect the inner workings of the soda machine, figure out which cable belongs to the dispenser that holds the drink that you want, and then send an electrical pulse on that wire to trigger the dispenser to release the drink. But that would be a horrible consumer experience. Instead, you just want a button to press to make it easy for you to understand how to operate the machine and get the soda from it that you want.

Okay, here's the part where I lift the veil on how that stock class could be implemented by inheritance.
This is not the best code. It's simple code intended to showcase a simple point. Don't start using inheritance for everything you can think of.
public abstract class Stock
{
    public int Level { get; protected set; } = 0;

    public virtual void IncreaseBy(int amount)
    {
        this.Level += amount;
    }

    public virtual void ReduceBy(int amount)
    {
        this.Level -= amount;
    }

    protected void SendAlert(string message)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(message);
    }
}

// Ephemeral stock can go into the negatives, no changes needed
public class EphemeralStock : Stock { }

// Physical stock cannot go into the negatives - hard rejection
public class PhysicalStock : Stock
{
    public override void ReduceBy(int amount)
    {
        if(this.Level < amount)
        {
            this.SendAlert($"ERROR - Not allowed");
        }
        else
        {
            base.ReduceBy(amount);
        }
    }
}

// Eventually consistent stock allows going into the negatives
// but considers this a likely problem that needs manual intervention
public class EventuallyConsistentPhysicalStock : Stock
{
    public override void ReduceBy(int amount)
    {
        if(this.Level < amount)
        {
            this.SendAlert($"Warning - stock is now negative, this needs intervention");
        }

        base.ReduceBy(amount);
    }
}


First of all, polymorphism is not doing more than one thing.  On contrary, each  doSomething() in your example is doing just one thing. So it's not one function doing different things, but several functions (each having a different fully qualified name), each doing one thing.
Then, I would be careful about overgeneralisation, which is the root of all other evil:

The referred question is not only about a boolean parameter, but about this parameter being passed along through a long chain of nested calls.  This is then very difficult to maintain: at the first level there are two possible behaviours,  at the second level, we come to four possible combinations (even if we know that 2 of them are not used, we have to mentally work with two alternatives per level), thus 32 at the 5th level. Good luck!
Even in simpler cases, boolean parameter could be misused to do really more than one thing, e.g. String crazyConcat (String a, String b, bool filterVowel) concatenating two strings if false, and filtering out the vowels if the parameter is true.
But by far not all boolean parameters lead to a function doing two things. Example: void switchLight (bool on) where the parameter corresponds to a target state, or int compare( Word a, Word b, bool caseSensitive)  where the same thing is done (comparing two words)  but case entitle or insensitive is a detail  at a lower level of abstraction.

So don't blindly follow rule of thumbs, but use your own judgement (and if it latter appears as wrong, just refactor).

With polymorphism, you kind of have two or more functions. And they don’t have a parameter, they “do the right thing” for their class. So each function can only do one thing.

Don’t disagree and didn’t downvote. But maybe flesh out this idea?

You are wrong in both of your basis. Therefore, your question makes no sense. This is how:
1. A Statement Is Not A Function
The mindset to keep breaking down functions ultimately results in having each function just as a container of a statement. The advantage of having functions is lost.
A function is supposed to perform a process. A process by definition is multi-step. There has to be multiple statements in a function.
If the algorithm is complex then the complexity dont go away whatever you do. You have to put it somewhere. The trick is to have multiple levels and have complexity manageable at each level. Bundling multiple statements in a function make the function carry some of the complexity. If you have very small functions then that complexity is not handled there and then you have to ultimately deal with it at class or package level. The class and package levels have, in addition, their own complexities to deal with.
A Function Should Handle Both If And Else Branches As Long As The Branches Are Not Long
A single statement in an if-branch, with a single statement in an else-branch are just two statements. Your function can and should have both of these statements.
If the if-condition is complex (have AND or OR) then its multiple statements itself. The action after that can be multiple statements too. Same with else-condition and else-actions.
If you want a threshold have 3 or more statements in a function. Never have only one statement in a function. If there are two statements then its a judgement call.
Often when you are reading such branches the main thing you want to see is how different the branches are. Its easy to have that comparison when both are in front of you at the same place.
The Final Check - Reusability
You should not break a function into multiple functions just because it has more than a set number of lines. The number of lines is a necessary but not sufficient reason. You also have to look at reusability. Do the smaller function stand on its own? Is their a use case where you would need only that much functionality?
Is there a scenario where you attach a file but not to an email? Yes, there is. You can attach a file to a document such as a MS Word document or a MS One Note document. If your logic is general enough to handle these cases then sure have a separate function.
The only other valid reason is if a part of functionality is optional. Do you always attach a file when you write an email? No, you don't. Therefore there can be a method at top that sometimes call this method and sometimes not.
Note that I said method, not function. You are now in the territory of passing some of the complexity to a class. You will have an Email class now with a public method and that method will sometimes call the private method that do the attachment of file.
If there is a perfect cohesion, either you need all parts or none of them, then there is no reusability of break away functions. What you need then is a multi-part function. A long function that do one part of the algorithm then the next and with very limited use of common variables, just one common variable usually.
2. Polymorphism Is Not Branching
Polymorphism do not deal with branching of control flow. Polymorphism is having a different implementation altogether.
Having branches is irrelevant to polymorphism. There may or may not be branching in the implementations. A lion can make sound (roar) no matter who is around, the behavior is not conditional. A fox however can only make sound if certain conditions are met, the behavior is conditional.
The entire implementation of making sound is different in the two polymorphic functions. The whole algorithm is different, from the start. Its not like it become different only after the branching happens. The fox do not roar even if conditions for making sound are met.
Polymorphism Is Psuedo-Branching And The Conditions Are Different Too
As said earlier, polymorphism is irrelevant to branching. Polymorphism has what can be called psuedo-branching. Its picking of a different algorithm. Its not dividing the control flow in two branches within one algorithm.
The condition which decide which of the psuedo-branch to take is based on the entirety of the object - its type, its fields, its behavior - its not based on one variable or one field of the object.

Downvote within a minute or so of posting, hmm, are you sure you have read the answer?

I did not downvote (yet), but after reading most of your answer I am convinced you overinterpreted (maybe misintepreted) several parts of the question.

@Doc Brown Read the whole answer before you make an opinion. There is no such thing as over interpretation. If a question is based on assumptions that are ALL wrong then the question cannot be answered for the same reason you cannot shoot a unicorn. Its not enough to say here that x is wrong, one need to prove that its wrong and thats what the answer did.
